# Can't enable IPv4 forwarding via adb shell

Tags: shell, android, adb

I've got a rooted Android phone and am trying to enable IPv4 forwarding via `adb shell`.  If I do

```bash
host$ adb shell
phone$ su -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

then it works just fine.

However,

```bash
host$ adb shell su -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

produces

```
/system/bin/sh: can't create /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward: Permission denied
```

even though `adb shell cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` shows that the file already exists.

Comment: Try `adb shell 'su -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"'` (another layer of quotes)

Comment: Huh.  That works.  Why would that be necessary?  In my experience, `adb shell` usually works quite well with multiple arguments (e.g., `adb shell echo foo bar`).

Comment: I don't know how `adb shell` is implemented, but I assume it's related to how it's parsing your command (wordsplitting etc). Not writing an answer as I can't explain it.